# TImber error: PHP Warning: {{item.permalink}} is deprecated, use {{item.link}} instead

Tags: wordpress, timber

I've upgraded an ancient version of the Timber plugin on Wordpress to the most current. I've gone through the 1.x upgrade guide and made all the Routes and deprecated function changes.

However, in the log file, I'm getting a lot of repeated PHP Warning errors for any one page load:

```
PHP Warning:  {{item.permalink}} is deprecated, use {{item.link}} 
instead in /Users/chris/sites/staging/wp-
content/plugins/timber-library/lib/Helper.php on line 210
```

but only points to the Timber Helper file. It doesn't point to an actual line of code I'm using. It looks like the Timber function that throws this error is doing it on a 'general' basis?

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

If this helps, here's the beginning of the PHP stack trace associated with each error above:

```
[19-Jul-2017 15:19:12 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[19-Jul-2017 15:19:12 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() 
/Users/chris/sites/staging/index.php:0
[19-Jul-2017 15:19:12 UTC] PHP   2. require() 
/Users/chris/sites/staging/index.php:17
[19-Jul-2017 15:19:12 UTC] PHP   3. require_once() . 
/Users/chris/sites/staging/wp-blog-header.php:19
[19-Jul-2017 15:19:12 UTC] PHP   4. include() . 
/Users/chris/sites/staging/wp-includes/template-
loader.php:74
[19-Jul-2017 15:19:12 UTC] PHP   5. Timber\Timber::render() 
/Users/chris/sites/staging/wp-
content/themes/staging/page.php:35
[19-Jul-2017 15:19:12 UTC] PHP   6. Timber\Timber::fetch() 
/Users/chris/sites/staging/wp-content/plugins/timber-
library/lib/Timber.php:379
[19-Jul-2017 15:19:12 UTC] PHP   7. Timber\Timber::compile() 
/Users/chris/sites/staging/wp-content/plugins/timber-
library/lib/Timber.php:352
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `permalink()` was deprecated in version 0.20.0 for posts and in version 0.21.7 for menu items.

This means that in your Twig file, you could have a link

```
<a href="{{ post.permalink }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

This now needs to be

```
<a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

Your error message seems to be triggered by a link in the navigation, so you need to check your Twig file where the navigation menu is generated, and replace `.permalink` with `.link`.

You could also search for `.permalink` in all your Twig files to find the parts you need to change. Unfortunately, the error message doesn’t point to the exact lines you need to change, it only gives you a hint that you use a deprecated method that you need to change.

Comment: Thanks so much. The stack referenced page.php above in step #5, but the .twig error, which was {{nav.permalink}} was buried in several includes a few layers deep, so the specific file name wasn't referenced.

The problem child lay in a section of code that was in the middle of a section of code within HTML comments. Thanks for your help!